# deleting items from database PHP SQL

Tags: php, mysql

i'm trying to delete a item from my database. deleting is successful but there is two problems:

1. showing this error when i've run this code for first time:

> Notice: Undefined index: delete in C:\wamp\www\source\admin_delete_user.php on line 46

**line 46: if($_POST['delete'])**

2. when i've delete a item from database, nothing appears at first and i need to refresh to see the results.

**code:**

```
<form name="form2" method="post" action="" > 
  <?php

   $db_host = 'localhost';
   $db_name= 'site';
   $db_table= 'tablesite';
   $db_user = 'root';
   $db_pass = '';




$con = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass) or die("خطا در اتصال به پايگاه داده");

mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $con);
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'", $con);
mysql_query("SET character_set_connection = 'utf8'", $con);

$selected=mysql_select_db($db_name, $con) or die("خطا در انتخاب پايگاه داده");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET  utf8");
$dbresult=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  tablesite",$con);
echo "کاربری که قصد حذفش را دارید انتخاب نمایید: ";
echo '<br/>';

echo '<select name="delete">';

while($amch=mysql_fetch_assoc($dbresult))
{
   echo '<option value="'.$amch['id_user'].'">'.$amch['username'].'</option>';
}
echo '</select>'; ?> <br/>
 <input name="submit2" type="submit" value="حذف" />

</form>

<?php
if($_POST['delete'])
{
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_name= 'site';
$db_table= 'tablesite';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pass = '';


$con = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass) or die("خطا در اتصال به پايگاه داده");

mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $con);
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'", $con);
mysql_query("SET character_set_connection = 'utf8'", $con);

$selected=mysql_select_db($db_name, $con) or die("خطا در انتخاب پايگاه داده");
 $ins = "DELETE FROM tablesite 
         where id_user='" . mysql_escape_string($_POST['delete']) . "'";
         $dbresult=mysql_query($ins,$con);
echo "('" . mysql_escape_string($_POST['delete']) . "')";

}
?>
```

Comment: A `Notice` is _not_ an `Error`.

Comment: @arkascha: a notice do not has good view when user is working in site

Comment: You mean you visualize such stuff in your web view? Switch that off in your php settings! If at all, that should only be configured for debugging and development, but _never_ for production usage! Take a look at the `display_errors` settings inside your `php.ini` configuration file.

Comment: @arkascha A well-written website should not produce any notices.

Comment: @syck That undoubtedly is true. But it does not change the fact that error display has to be switched off on a production site, or does it? :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To fix the first problem, you'll need to add (using &&) `isset($_POST['delete'])` to the if statement. That'll do the check if the variable even exists.

In order to fix the second one... You most likely need to move the whole deletion part above the data parsing. Then it will be deleted first and only then parsed, not the other way around.

Comment: 1.what is using 2. are you sure there is not any way to deleting first?

Comment: Just add the `isset()` part to the `if` statement and use the AND operator (add the `isset()` before you do `!empty()`). Well, you can only delete first if the deletion code is above the parsing code, right? That does make sense.